# Adding scissor with dotted line at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got an image of a scissor cutting across a dotted line, something like the one in the image:

[image: scissor with dotted lines]

Basically, I want the image to be placed on the footer of all my pages.  I want the dotted lines to go horizontally on the page so that about 90% of the width of the page is filled with the dotted lines and then, I would like the scissor to be placed after that, so that it looks like the scissor is cutting across the page.

I would like to do this with CSS and need this to work on all screen resolutions.  But, the problem is, how do I implement this so that it works on all browsers and all versions.  Would appreciate it if anyone could help on this.  If this could be done easily with jQuery, I am open to that as well.

This is what I have thus far:

```
.bottom_border_scissor img{
  margin-top: -23px;
 }
.bottom_border_scissor {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 81%;
  background: url(../images/bottom_without_dot.png) repeat-x 0 center transparent;

}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what code you have tried so we can assist? The SO community aren't here to write the code for you! http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: You can do this with a single image (the scissors) and some CSS (a dashed/dotted border). No JS required.

Comment: for dotted border try **border-style:dotted**

Comment: Oh, crud-bucket. @ajtrichards should I remove my answer?

Comment: Sorry for not adding my code.  I basically tried doing this with two images (the scissors plus dotted lines image is more graphical than the one I have attached and couldn't be done with giving it a dotted border-style).  I did it with one image that is just the dotted lines and another that is just the scissors.  Basically, I was taking about 10px of the dotted lines, and then just repeating it to fill the page.  And then, I placed the scissors with margin-left: 81%;.  It basically gets the job done and works when I resize it in most browsers.  But, it doesn't work in IE 7 and 8.

Comment: Edited question to add what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update version added to answer on 2018-02-16

## Version 1 - Additional Container Required

Here's how I'd skin this cat...

I'd create a div that took up 90% of the page width. I'd give this div a background-image of some scissors (minus any dotted lines). Finally, I would place a child div inside and style this to appear as the dotted lines.

[image: Scissors without dotted line]

### HTML

```
<div id="scissors">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#scissors {
    height: 43px; /* image height */
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto auto;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXciH.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}
#scissors div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    border-top: 3px dashed black;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4CxZH/

---

## Version 2 - Single Element

### HTML

```
<div id="scissors"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#scissors {
    height: 43px; /* image height */
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto auto;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXciH.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scissors:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    border-top: 3px dashed black;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/4CxZH/99/

Comment: Thanks gvee.  I will definitely give this a try.  I might have to get rid of my dotted line image and then just go with the dashed border to get this working.  I guess functionality is more important that looks.

Comment: New method added! Now only needs a single element